# Kafka state store not available in distributed environment

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a business application with the following versions

- spring boot(2.2.0.RELEASE) spring-Kafka(2.3.1-RELEASE)
  spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka(2.2.1-RELEASE)
  spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-core(3.0.3-RELEASE)
  spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams(3.0.3-RELEASE)

We have around 20 batches.Each batch using 6-7 topics to handle the business.Each service has its own state store to maintain the status of the batch whether its running/Idle.
Using the below code to query th store

```
@Autowired
private InteractiveQueryService interactiveQueryService;
      public ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, String> fetchKeyValueStoreBy(String storeName) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                log.info("Waiting for state store");
                return new ReadOnlyKeyValueStoreWrapper<>(interactiveQueryService.getQueryableStore(storeName,
                        QueryableStoreTypes.<String, String> keyValueStore()));
            } catch (final IllegalStateException e) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

When deploying the application in one instance(Linux machine) every thing is working fine.While deploying the application in 2 instance we find the folowing observations

1. state store is available in one instance and other dosen't have.
2. When the request is being processed by the instance which has the state store every thing is fine.
3. If the request falls to the instance which does not have state store the application is waiting in the while loop indefinitley(above code snippet).
4. While the instance without store waiting indefinitely and if we kill the other instance the above code returns the store and it was    processing perfectly.

No clue what we are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have multiple Kafka Streams processors running with interactive queries, the code that you showed above will not work the way you expect. It only returns results, if the keys that you are querying are on the same server. In order to fix this, you need to add the property - `spring.cloud.stream.kafka.streams.binder.configuration.application.server: <server>:<port>` on each instance. Make sure to change the server and port to the correct ones on each server. Then you have to write code similar to the following:

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.state.HostInfo hostInfo = interactiveQueryService.getHostInfo("store-name",
                        key, keySerializer);

if (interactiveQueryService.getCurrentHostInfo().equals(hostInfo)) {

    //query from the store that is locally available
}
else {
    //query from the remote host
}
```

Please see the [reference docs](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/3.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#_interactive_queries) for more information. 
Here is a [sample code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/master/kafka-streams-samples/kafka-streams-interactive-query-advanced/src/main/java/kafka/streams/interactive/query/KafkaStreamsInteractiveQuerySample.java#L203) that demonstrates that.